# How to compare two lists with different order?

Tags: python

I need to compare two lists without taking their order into account:

```
list_a = ['one', 'two', 'three']
list_b = ['three', 'one', 'two']
```

when I try to compare them, it returns `False`:

```
>>> list_a == list_b
False
```

Both lists have many elements, what would be the optimal way to compare them?

Comment: sort them first?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to compare whether both lists result in the same `Counter`.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list_a = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> list_b = ['three', 'one', 'two']
>>> Counter(list_a) == Counter(list_b)
True
>>> list_b = ['three', 'one', 'two', 'two']
>>> Counter(list_a) == Counter(list_b)
False
>>> set(list_a) == set(list_b)
True # False positive
```

Another solution would be to sort both lists and then compare them. The `Counter` approach should be more efficient for big lists since it has linear time complexity (i.e. O(n)) while sorting is only pseudo-linear (i.e. O(n*log(n)).

Comment: I tried it and it worked perfectly. I think this is the most efficient way to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to compare a `set` of each list

```
>>> list_a = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> list_b = ['three', 'one', 'two']
>>> set(list_a) == set(list_b)
True
```

Otherwise if there may be duplicates, and you want to ensure they have the same number of each element then you could do

```
>>> sorted(list_a) == sorted(list_b)
True
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I tried it and it worked perfectly!

Comment: This can actually lead to false positives: `list_a = ["a", "a", b"] ; list_b = ["a", "b", "b"] ; set(list_a) == set(list_b) # True`

Answer (score 1):

`Counter` of module collections will be the way to go. As you have strings and as show in the answers:

```
from collections import Counter
.....
if Counter(list_a) == Counter(list_b): # True or False
```

if the list have any unhashable elements (other than string and number), like objects etc, you might want to take out their id and make another list and compare their Counter.

```
...
if Counter(map(id,list_a)) == Counter(map(id,list_b)):
    print "same unhashable things in list_a and list_b"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It worked too.